# Is it possible to add an Azure Functions project to a .Net Core Api Solution and use a common repository?

Tags: api, asp.net-core, repository, asp.net-core-webapi, azure-function-app

Our team has an existing .Net Core API solution.  I'd like to add a series of function apps in a V2 functions project.  This would allow reuse of the existing database repositories.

Is this possible / rational?

Comment: What in the world did this get voted down for?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible and rational. You can deploy just the functions app project, and have it running on Azure. Just remember to redeploy whenever there is a change in the dependent projects.

Comment: I set it up and had it compile locally, but it wasn't responding.  Suppose I should have said that in the question...  Any idea why it didn't respond?

Comment: Does is respond when you deploy? If it works on Azure, perhaps, there is a firewall/port issue to access it locally.